# How to update all prices in quote item table in magento2

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

**I have `quote id` I want to update `price` , `base_row_total` & other prices related field in quote should i want to set price only rest field should automatically update is this possible or i am thinking wrong .
please help thanks in advance**

I am using the below Code but its shores only sku,name,store_id,i checked default magento cart Api its storing all vales in quote Table i want to do the same but its not working for me:

```
 $product = $this->product->get($this->sku);

        $quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();

        $quoteItem->setProduct($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can changes price of all items of a quote.

**Use**

```
$QuoteObjectitem->setCustomPrice($YourPrice);
$QuoteObjectitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($YourPrice);
```

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `quote_item` table, you have the `price` column in that table. If you have an object of $quoteItem, you could set the price directly:

```
$quoteItem->setPrice($priceHere)
```

Also here is another answer from @AmitBera, how to update a quote item:

[Magento 2 : Updating quote item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160861/magento-2-updating-quote-item)

```
$item = $quote->getItemById($item->getId());
if (!$item) {
  continue;
}
$item->setQty((double) $qty);
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$item->save();
```