# Quote item price changes

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

Can someone suggest if there is any function to update the quote item tables price columns

> `(custom_price,original_custom_price,row_total,qty,price,base_price,row_total,base_row_total,price_incl_tax,base_price_incl_tax,row_total_incl_tax,base_row_total_incl_tax
>   etc)`

changes internally rather than calculating and updating each column manually?

When a product price change happens, the quote details are not changing. I was trying to add code for the same while checking out, where mini cart details were not getting updated.

Comment: whether you would like to change the product price after add to cart a product in magento2 please confirm?

Comment: I wanted to update the prices of cart items(in quote items table) to the latest price, while checking out.I am right now adding in the checkout controller.

Comment: I refered to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140402/how-to-update-all-prices-in-quote-item-table-in-magento2?rq=1 but only custom_price and original_custom_price are getting set

Comment: please follow the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181867/change-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento2/181873#181873

Comment: could u please confirm the exact scenario u would like to add price (update price for the item)?

Comment: please try the below answer the quote item prices will update using event observer concept when after add to cart. please let us know your comments.

Comment: I am not using an observer.I am writing it in the checkout controller page & using the same code which you have suggested.Still it is not updating the other prices

Comment: Please try the steps below which i have mentioned. and get back with your comments.

Comment: I have followed the steps which you have suggested.And while adding product to cart the prices of quote items are getting updated (using the observer) but the same code when tried from controller only custom_price and original_custom_price are getting changed.Any idea on why it's  not updating the prices.

Comment: by default magento having some list of design patterns this is one of the magento having pattern called events and observer based on the user perform actions particular event will be trigger and execute the (observer) piece of code internally like as shown given example so that the particular db table/s data will be updated.

Comment: if your issue has been solved please accept my answer would be appreciated. thanks Happy coding

Answer (score 6):

You can update cart item price using customer login observer. While customer login the cart item will updated with new price.

**app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="vendor_customer_customer_login" instance="Vendor\Customer\Observer\CustomerloginObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Customer/Observer/CustomerloginObserver.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

/**
 * Class CustomerloginObserver
 * 
 */
class CustomerloginObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var Customer
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $_product;

    /**
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * CustomerloginObserver constructor.
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param Customer $customer
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param Product $_product
     * @param Item $quoteFactory
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        Customer $customer,
        Cart $cart,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        Product $_product,
        Item $quoteFactory,
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        Address $address
    ) {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_product = $_product;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {


        $id = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        // check session is active or not.

        if ($session) {

            $itemId = 0;
            $qty = 0;
            $quoteId = 0;
            $sessionItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();

            foreach ($sessionItems as $session_item) {
                $qty = (int) $session_item['qty'];
                $productId = $session_item['product_id'];
                $product = $this->_product->load($productId);
                $setcustomprice = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($session_item['item_id']);
                $uom = $product->getUom();

                    if ($price > 0) {
                        $customprice = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($session_item['item_id']);
                        $customprice->setCustomPrice($price);
                        $customprice->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                        $customprice->save();
                        $quoteId = $session_item['quote_id'];
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($quoteId) {
                $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> First create a module using free module creator tool called silk software

[Magento 2 Module Creator Tool Using Silk Software](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php)

and enable using following commands below.

```
 1. php bin/magento module:enable Tw_Cart
 2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 3. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> create events.xml in the path:- app/code/Tw/Cart/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="Tw_Cart_Addtocart_Customprice" instance="TW\Cart\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> create CustomPrice.php in the path: app/code/Tw/Cart/Observer/ & keep the below code

```
<?php
    namespace TW\Cart\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            /* Code here */
            $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
            $price = 400; //set your price here
            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $logger->info("success !!!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: 2 weeks of head scratching as to why my custom prices weren't carrying over in to the totals sorted! Thanks :)

Comment: I implemented above code. It's working only first time  added to cart when cart is empty. second time it's taking original value of product.